# How to select new IFrame using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I wanted to select an **Iframe** and Enter values in the Body . I am trying with the below code.

**HTML code:**

```
 <iFrame id="4564654_content_ifr">
     <html>
       <head>
         <body id="tiny">
             <div aria-lable="New Compose body">
                 <br>
             </div>
         </body>
       </head>
      </html>
  </iFrame>
```

**Selenium code:**

```
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'content_ifr')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tiny']/div[1]")).sendKeys("Happy New IFrame");
```

But I could not able to enter values.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of sending keys, you can set `innerHTML` directly.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'content_ifr')]")));

WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Happy New IFrame'", body);
```

If you are testing some kind of WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE, feel free to have a look at this article:

[Test WYSIWYG editors using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Then you might be able to set content through editor's API directly. It's known to have issues with `sendKeys` in Firefox, but should be fine with Chrome or PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below May help you.

```
WebElement sg= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='4564654_content_ifr']"));
                driver.switchTo().frame(sg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> iframeElements= driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println("The total number of iframes are " + iframeElements.size());
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("it is on frame1");
```

Comment: Some times, With frame name it may not work. So Using frame index, you can easily handle switching to frames