# Unable to enter text into TinyMCE rich text editor

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I`m trying to entering a text into TinyMCE rich text in Firefox 27.0 using selenium webdriver 2.40.0 but it failed to work.

Here is the line of code:

driver.switchTo().frame("summary_ifr");

driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("abc"));

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Saurabh

Comment: Tell me what error you are getting??

Comment: I was not getting any error while running the test scripts but unable to write the text into TinyMCE rich text editor using selenium webdriver 2.40.0

Comment: I feel the way you are identifying the text editor is wrong. Can you post the html for the frame.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select new IFrame using Selenium WebDriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489986/how-to-select-new-iframe-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @Vinay But the same code is working correctly in chrome browser. I don`t think so that identifying the text editor is wrong

Comment: @Vinay Though it points to the Rich text editor to write something there but due to some reasons cannot be possible to do it.

Comment: Possible solution by Yi Zeng - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21688223/2872258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created an example which worked for me in Firefox with WebDriver 2.40.0 :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.tinymce.com/index.php");
driver.switchTo().frame("editMe_ifr");
WebElement editor = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Heading</h1>Hello World'", editor);
```

Please see if this helps you anyway!

Comment: Thanks. It worked in Firefox. But I have a question how would I insert initialized variable value into the text editor through executeScript. For example: I have a String variable X="abc" then how can we put this variable within "arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Y'" in place of "Y". So it will insert "abc" into the text editor.

Comment: Use this code : `String X = "abc"; jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '" +X +"'", editor);`

Comment: Thanks. I just used the same approach and it worked. Thanks once again for the help.